# How to ask if an existing library / software exist?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that is about to closed:

[question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/326413/midi-library-for-stm32?noredirect=1#comment763928_326413)

There I ask if there exists a library. I wonder, how I should rephrase the question to make it a better question ... since I googled, and cannot find one.

So what is the best way to ask for an 'appropriate' question about the existence of a library or piece of software in general?

Answer (score 2):

The key is finding the right venue for your question in the first place. I've migrated your question to [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/45448/midi-library-for-stm32).

Comment: I noticed ...I wonder if there are people ever heard about STM32 in software recommendations.

Comment: I think the question was better off here.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: The community doesn't agree with you. It already had 4 close votes, for being a request for product recommendation.

Comment: I just think it's more likely to get an answer here rather than there.  I understand closing it, but software recommendations is a poor target.  A programmers stack would have been much more appropriate.